# How can I install packages from the RHEL6's Optional Channel via Kickstart?

Tags: linux, redhat, puppet, kickstart, rhel6

I typically install `puppet` via `kickstart`. Apparently, `puppet` now requires a package (`libselinux-ruby`) that is included in the Red Hat's Optional Channel.

I was under the impression I could only use the Optional Channel by assigning the appropriate Software Channel entitlement after the server was provisioned with RHN.

Does this mean that we cannot use `kickstart` to install packages that are in the Optional Channel? If that is not the case, how would we configure our `kickstart` accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done is:

1. In RHN I set up an "[activation key](https://rhn.redhat.com/network/account/activation_keys/list.pxt)" (look for it in "Systems") that is subscribed to the Optional channel. It's possible to do this with one key for all architectures.
2. made a kickstart that includes all these bits:

   ```
   repo --name=epel --baseurl=http://LOCALEPELMIRROR/.../epel/6/x86_64/
   %package
   ...
   epel-release

   %post
   ...
   /usr/sbin/rhnreg_ks --activationkey=$ACTIVATIONKEY
   rpm --import /usr/share/rhn/RPM-GPG-KEY
   rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
   rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
   rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release-2
   ...
   yum install puppet
   ```

Comment: I was under the impression that installation key and activation keys were different. Is that not the case?

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin: Some of my internal docs might be using outdated terminology. You're right, it's "activation" keys I'm talking about, not "installation" keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would download necessary package(s) on the installation server, together with the public key it was signed with. Then I'd use `%post` in `kickstart` to import the key, and download and install the package(s). Then you can use yum to install `puppet`, because only now it will have its prerequisites installed.

You could also add needed repositories to `/etc/yum.repos.d`, to be able to pull updates later.