# Can Satellite registration be done in Kickstart's `%pre` stanza?

Tags: redhat, kickstart, rhel7

In a [presentation](http://people.redhat.com/tcameron/summit2010/satellite/RHN_SatPowerUserTipsTricks-Cameron.pdf) from 2010 RedHat Summit, I saw Satellite registration (`rhnreg_ks`) done in a `%pre` stanza, while RedHat's [current docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.5/html/Client_Configuration_Guide/chap-Client_Configuration_Guide-Implementing_Kickstart.html) (as well as [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/316912/315657)) do it in `%post`. Registering in `%post` worked for me, but then I have to run `yum install` there to get packages from child channels, instead of keeping everything in `%packages`.

Trying to replicate the code for registering in `%pre` from that presentation (see pages 149-153) fails with no errors reported (even with `--erroronfail`) or pre-logs generated -- but the host is definitely not subscribed because the packages from the activation's child channel are reported missing during the `%packages` phase.

Has anyone succeeded in this?